# Error when executing Sed command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sed

I have one file `exa1.txt` which contains the following text:

```
wget -O backward-cpp-$VERSION.tar.gz https://github.com/bombela/backward-cpp/archive/v$VERSION.tar.gz
tar xf backward-cpp-$VERSION.tar.gz
testString
```

I need to append/insert following line using linux `sed` command

```
sed -i '/uctx->uc_mcontext.regs->nip/a \#elif defined(__s390x__)\n\                error_addr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(uctx->uc_mcontext.psw.addr);' backward-cpp-$VERSION/backward.hpp
```

I tried the following

Option-1

```
sed -i  '/tar xf backward-cpp-$VERSION.tar.gz/a\
sed -i '/uctx\->uc_mcontext.regs\->nip/a \\#elif defined\(__s390x__\)\n\ error_addr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(uctx->uc_mcontext.psw.addr);' backward-cpp-$VERSION/backward.hpp' exa1.txt  /$BUILDDIR/envoy/ci/build_container/build_recipes/backward.sh
```

Option-2

```
sed -i -e 's/testString/sed -i '/uctx->uc_mcontext.regs->nip/a \\#elif defined\(__s390x__\)\\n\\                error_addr = reinterpret_cast<void*>\(uctx->uc_mcontext.psw.addr\);' backward-cpp-$VERSION/backward.hpp/g' exa1.txt
```

but I get this error

```
-bash: nip/a: No such file or directory
-bash:  backward-cpp-$VERSION/backward.hpp/g: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You're using apostrophes without escaping them. They should surround the sed-Command and MUST NOT be used inside without escaping.

Comment: Please tell me how to insert this line in any file at any place using sed command

Comment: sed -i '/uctx->uc_mcontext.regs->nip/a \#elif defined(__s390x__)\n\                error_addr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(uctx->uc_mcontext.psw.addr);' backward-cpp-$VERSION/backward.hpp

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add some lines to the end of a file, then you have no need to use sed:

```
$ cat exa1.txt - > output <<EOF
some lines you want to insert
go here
EOF
```

In the command, `-` refers to standard input, which is the contents of the heredoc between `<<EOF` and `EOF`.

Now `output` contains the con`cat`enation of the contents of the first file, and any lines you put between `<<EOF` and `EOF`. Remember to escape `$` if you don't want them to be expanded by the shell, otherwise on shells such as Bash, you can use `<<'EOF'` so that everything is treated literally.

To achieve an "in-place" edit, just overwrite the original file using `mv`.

Or, just create another script that first runs the script in `exa1.txt` and then whatever additional commands.

Comment: need to edit one file at runtime while executing jenkins build script.

Comment: @Anuj I edited my answer

Comment: Can we achieve it through 'sed' command to insert multiple lines with special characters. In my scenario  have to write jenkins build shell script where i have to edit lots of files at run time. Please help.